# Unreliable results when scanning multiple ports concurrently

Tags: go, networking, tcp, port-scanning

**Background**:

I was reading through Black Hat Go where the author presents a simple port scanner that uses go routines[1](https://github.com/blackhat-go/bhg/blob/master/ch-2/tcp-scanner-too-fast/main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 9000; i++ {
        go func(j int) {
            address := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", j)
            conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            conn.Close()
            fmt.Printf("%d open\n", j)
        }(i)
    }
}
```

And then he mentions the following:

> Scanning an excessive number of hosts or ports simultaneously may
>   cause network or system limitations to skew your results.

To test it, I started 2 php servers[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) on ports 8000 and 8500 and ran the above code to scan my local ports.

Each time it gave me inconsistent results. Sometimes it'd detect both the open ports, sometimes it would not.

**Question**:

1. Are the inconsistent results due to some limitations in TCP?
2. Is there a way to calculate the optimal number of ports that can be scanned in parallel so that the results remain correct?

**Edit**:

I seem to have missed out waitgroups in the above code.

Besides that, is there anything else (OS limitation or protocol limitation) that prevents concurrent port scans over a large range?

Comment: Can you add code to print `err` and add some samples of the output to your question? One limitation might be the number of open file descriptors each process is allowed to have.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You were right! I was hitting the `socket: too many open files` error. 

Can you write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main function will exit as soon as the for loop has finished. If the main function exits, so do all goroutines started by it. You need to wait for the goroutines to finish. That can be achieved this via [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync?tab=doc#WaitGroup), for example.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // This will help you to keep track of the goroutines
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 9000; i++ {

        // Increment the counter for each goroutine you start.
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(j int) {

            // Make sure the wait group counter is decremented when the goroutine exits
            defer wg.Done()

            address := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", j)
            conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", address, 2 * time.Second)
            if err != nil {
               return
            }
            conn.Close()
            fmt.Printf("%d open\n", j)
        }(i)
    }

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish before exiting main
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**EDIT:** For me, it turned out that the code as is did not work due to a lack of file descriptors. The following function works reliably.

It needs better error handling, but does the trick

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var minPort = 1
var maxPort = 65535
var timeout = 2 * time.Second
const parallel = 50

func main(){
    fmt.Println("portscan called")

    // Create a buffered channel with a size equal to the number of goroutines
    ctrl := make(chan int, parallel)

    // Keep track of the currently active goroutines
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for p := 1; p <= parallel; p++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        // Start a goroutine...
        go func(p int) {
            log.Printf("Starting goroutine %d", p)

            // ...listening to the control channel.
            // For every value this goroutine reads from the
            // channel...
            for i := range ctrl {
                address := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", i)

                // ...try to conncet to the port.
                conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", address, timeout)
                if err == nil {
                    conn.Close()
                    log.Printf("[%3d]: %5d open", p, i)
                }
                // TBD: ERROR HANDLING!!!
            }

            // If the channel is closed, this goroutine is done.
            wg.Done()
            log.Printf("[%3d]: Exiting", p)
        }(p)
    }

    // Fill the control channel with values.
    // If the channel is full, the write operation
    // to the channel will block until one of the goroutines
    // reads a value from it.
    for i := minPort; i <= maxPort; i++ {
        ctrl <- i
    }
    // We have sent all values, so the channel can be closed.
    // The goroutines will finish their current connection attempt,
    // notice that the channel is closed and will in turn call wg.Done().
    close(ctrl)

    // When all goroutines have announced that they are done, we can exit.
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I ran the above code and it still fails to detect the open ports correctly when I scan over 1 to 9000. It seems to work if I bring it down to a smaller range.

Comment: Run it with a debugger or log the errors: since a TCP connection usually needs two file descriptors to be opened, you most likely run out of available file descriptors.  I am working on a solution that will chunk accordingly.